# How to generate BRAM using vivado HLS?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado, bram

I am trying to create an IP using Vivado HLS. I have a lot of arrays. I have given directives to infer BRAM, with my array *bram_arr* like

```
#pragma HLS_RESOURCE variable=bram_arr core=RAM_1P_BRAM
set_directive_interface -mode bram "bram_init" bram_arr
```

Still I don't get a BRAM.

What should I do to infer BRAM for the array *bram_arr*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error, I could infer BRAM. I didn't get BRAM, because my array size was less (4). When I increased my array size to 1024, I could obtain BRAM inferred for the global variable *bram_arr*.

Here is the screenshot of the results:

[image: Resource Utilization]

As you can see it inferred 18K BRAM for my Kintex 7 device.

Thank you.